# Flash AS3 event listener error

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, addeventlistener, event-listener

I have this bit of AS3 code. it loads an external .swf file and is supposed to play it. I've added an event listener to run when the file is loaded. The function it calls moves the video to the bottom most layer so the buttons still show and then plays the file. The problem is the event listener never triggers. Can any one help? Thanks in advance.

Dave

```
    var loadit:Loader = new Loader();
    var load_request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.friedmanllp.com/video/intro.swf");
    loadit.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);
    //swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgressHandler);
    //loadit.load(load_request);

    function onCompleteHandler(loadEvent:Event) {
        addChildAt(loadEvent.currentTarget.content, 1);
        loadit.load(load_request);
    }
```

Comment: why your first call //loadit.load(load_request); commented? It seems your loader never loads any data

Comment: What is the purpose of `onCompleteHandler` event? How it dispatche before call the load method?

Comment: I had it commented out as the video was going before the video got appropriated to the correct layer. So you would hear it but not see it for a few seconds. May have been Event.COMPLETE. I first tried to move the load event AFTER the addChildAt line of code. SO... I used Event.INIT and that took care of it. Could you please remove the -1. I feel this is a very valid question even though I ended up solving it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using Event.INIT:

```
    var loadit:Loader = new Loader();
    var load_request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.friedmanllp.com/video/intro.swf");
    loadit.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onCompleteHandler);  
    loadit.load(load_request);

    function onCompleteHandler(loadEvent:Event) {
        addChildAt(loadEvent.currentTarget.content, 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

A couple things are wrong.

First, your loader will never load because you never asked it to.  You have the load method call commented out.

Also, listen to crooksy88.  You need to listen to the contentLoaderInfo property for the completion event.  Listening to the Loader instance will not dispatch the event you are looking for.

A warning as well -- make sure your loadit variable is not being garbage collected!  If the code you posted is running within a function call, then you need to persist your Loader instance somewhere (to an instance variable, for example) to make sure it stays in memory.

Code should look something like this:

```
var load_request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.mydomain.com/mySubFolder/myExternal.swf");
var loadit:Loader = new Loader();
loadit.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgressHandler);
loadit.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);
loadit.load(load_request);

function onProgressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void
{
    trace("onProgressHandler(event)");
}

function onCompleteHandler(event:Event):void
{
    trace("onCompleteHandler(event)");
    addChildAt(loadit, 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the verbose response. I have solved it though by using Event.INIT instead Event.COMPLETE.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
loadit.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);
```

Comment: I tried that before, never worked. There is no preloaded for this. It just runs. Does that matter?

Answer (score 0):

A short version based on [Fingers](http://filimanjaro.com/fingers)

```
var loadIt:Loader = new Loader();
on(loadIt.contentLoaderInfo).complete += function (e:Event) {
    addChildAt(e.currentTarget.content, 1);
}
loadIt.load(new URLRequest("http://www.friedmanllp.com/video/intro.swf"));
```